# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) while adding Fabric in Application

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to add Fabric in my application. Everything is working fine if i am not configuring fabric in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method, but when I put code to configure Fabric, I'm getting error.

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

**Error :**

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Pods -> Build Settings -> Build Architectures Only - change to false

Comment: I removed pod and installed manually using and works fine. Thank you Guys.

Comment: @VikramChaudhary: Please upvote my answer, which works.

Comment: @TomSwayer If your answer is worked for me, I accept but it's not. I added the framework manually. I also found the solution for the pod. I will post an answer or via comment. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error, remove the Crashlytics framework and reinstall it. Later, check if it is on the bundle. This should solve the issue.

There is a very good article on the [crashlytics (firebase) site](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features)
It's very simple.